# Search file in Folder MVC ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, directory

I started working with MVC ASP.NET and i am stuck on 2 points.

1. How to search file in folder. For example if one file is inserted in folder then the system will pick this file and add display in list. (only newly inserted file).
2. Where should i add this code. Model or Control (not in view I guess).

Please help in this matter.

Comment: any guideline after giving me negative points

Answer (score 0):

You will be writing your codes in the controller. You got negative points, because you didnt do anything on your own.

cheers

Comment: -1 for not having said that in a comment but in an answer ;-)

Comment: A question cant be asked according to your knowledge, but a question is still a question. Not everyone is born in english speaking countries, so sometime they cant ask properly. If you have a gun, you would have killed this guy but unfortunately you just could give negative score. Misuse of power. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can search a file in the View or in the Controller. In below I will explain how to do it in the controller with AJAX.

Add this to your View:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function Check() {
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchFile")',
                data: '{fileName: ' + $('#input1').val() + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#result").val(result);                        
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {                       
                    alert(jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
                }
            });
   }
</script>
<div>
    <input id="input1">
    <button id="btnCheck" onclick="Check()"> Check </button>
    <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

And I must Add a controller for getting the file name from AJAX and searching it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchFile(string fileName)
{
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return Json(false);
    var relativePath = "~/YourFolder/" + fileName;
    var absolutePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(relativePath);            
    return Json(System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath));
}
```